# BERT: After pretraining 880000 step, why fine-tune not work?

Tags: transformer, bert, transfer-learning, pretrained-models, fine-tuning

I am using pretraining code from https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples

Pretrain parameters:

```
 15:47:02,534: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   init_checkpoint: bertbase3layer-extract-from-google
 15:47:02,534: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   optimizer_type: lamb
 15:47:02,534: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   max_seq_length: 64
 15:47:02,534: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   max_predictions_per_seq: 5
 15:47:02,534: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   do_train: True
 15:47:02,535: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   do_eval: False
 15:47:02,535: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   train_batch_size: 32
 15:47:02,535: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   eval_batch_size: 8
 15:47:02,535: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   learning_rate: 5e-05
 15:47:02,535: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   num_train_steps: 10000000
 15:47:02,535: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   num_warmup_steps: 10000
 15:47:02,535: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   save_checkpoints_steps: 1000
 15:47:02,535: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   display_loss_steps: 10
 15:47:02,535: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   iterations_per_loop: 1000
 15:47:02,535: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   max_eval_steps: 100
 15:47:02,535: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   num_accumulation_steps: 1
 15:47:02,535: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   allreduce_post_accumulation: False
 15:47:02,535: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   verbose_logging: False
 15:47:02,535: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   horovod: True
 15:47:02,536: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   report_loss: True
 15:47:02,536: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   manual_fp16: False
 15:47:02,536: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   amp: False
 15:47:02,536: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   use_xla: True
 15:47:02,536: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   init_loss_scale: 4294967296
 15:47:02,536: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   ?: False
 15:47:02,536: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   help: False
 15:47:02,536: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   helpshort: False
 15:47:02,536: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   helpfull: False
 15:47:02,536: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464   helpxml: False
 15:47:02,536: INFO tensorflow 140678508230464 **************************
```

Pretrain loss: (I remove nsp_loss)

```
{'throughput_train': 1196.9646684552622, 'mlm_loss': 0.9837073683738708, 'nsp_loss': 0.0, 'total_loss': 0.9837073683738708, 'avg_loss_step': 1.200513333082199, 'learning_rate': '0.00038143058'}
{'throughput_train': 1230.5063662500734, 'mlm_loss': 1.3001925945281982, 'nsp_loss': 0.0, 'total_loss': 1.3001925945281982, 'avg_loss_step': 1.299936044216156, 'learning_rate': '0.00038143038'}
{'throughput_train': 1236.4348949169155, 'mlm_loss': 1.473339319229126, 'nsp_loss': 0.0, 'total_loss': 1.473339319229126, 'avg_loss_step': 1.2444063007831574, 'learning_rate': '0.00038143017'}
{'throughput_train': 1221.2668264552692, 'mlm_loss': 0.9924975633621216, 'nsp_loss': 0.0, 'total_loss': 0.9924975633621216, 'avg_loss_step': 1.1603020071983337, 'learning_rate': '0.00038142994'}
```

Fine-tune code:

```
self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.00001).minimize(self.loss, global_step=self.global_step)
```

Fine-tune accuracy: (restore from my ckpt pretrained from https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples)

```
epoch 1:
training step 895429, loss 4.98, acc 0.079
dev loss 4.853, acc 0.092

epoch 2:
training step 895429, loss 4.97, acc 0.080
dev loss 4.823, acc 0.092

epoch 3:
training step 895429, loss 4.96, acc 0.081
dev loss 4.849, acc 0.092

epoch 4:
training step 895429, loss 4.95, acc 0.082
dev loss 4.843, acc 0.092
```

Without restore the pretrained ckpt:

```
epoch 1:
training step 10429, loss 2.48, acc 0.606
dev loss 1.604, acc 0.8036
```

Restore the google's BERT-Base pretrained ckpt. Or restore from a pretrained ckpt pretrained from https://github.com/guotong1988/BERT-GPU

```
epoch 1:
training loss 1.89, acc 0.761
dev loss 1.351, acc 0.869
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to AI SE! "fine-tune not work" is not a question, so please edit your post to explicitly ask a specific question. Moreover, note that programming questions are generally off-topic here. Here we focus on theoretical, social and philosophical aspects of AI. Your question seems to be a programming issue, so it's off-topic here.  See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
bert_output = bert_model.get_pooled_output()
```

to

```
bert_output = tf.reduce_mean(bert_model.get_sequence_output()[:,1:,:],1)
```